# Passing clipboard text to other activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My app targets API level 11 (3.0) or above. I want to utilise the Copy button from the Action Bar so that when TEXT is copied to Clipboard it will be sent to EditText of another activity and starts this activity.

Below is what I have done:

```
wvContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvContent);
wvContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

            final String text = clipboardManager.getText().toString();
            if(text!=null) 
                    {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(have_word, text);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
                        finish();
                        CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    } 
        }           
    });
```

I place this code under `onCreate`, but it does not work. The text is copied but the `NewActivity` is not started.

I wonder whether you guys can provide me a little help to solve this problem. Many thanks.

Comment: post error logs if any?

Comment: No error logs at all.@StinePike: In fact, I have tried your way but it did not help. What I a thinking is how code so that when Copy button from Action Bar is clicked, a new activity with copied text is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html#getPrimaryClip%28%29) instead as getText() is depecreated. [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html) you can find a nice example to use this to get clibpoard data.